# How to decrypt webhook payload of Transak?

Tags: php, encryption, payload

I am integrating Transak on our WordPress website. [Transak](https://transak.stoplight.io/) integration is completed but we are facing issue with the decryption of the webhook payload send by transak

Transak says "We send the webhook payload in an encrypted format. You have to decrypt it using your API_SECRET."

Transak decrypted webhook response is as below:

```
{body:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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
 MTk6NTU6MDUtMDc6MDAiLCJyZWZlcmVuY2VDb2RlIjoyMjYwNTZ9LCJldmVudElEIjoiT1JERVJfQ1JFQVRFRCIsImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6IjIwMjAtMTAtMTRUMTg6MDA6MDguOTcwWiJ9.abKj3GaKxB46V5MGQf0ouvo_bAx0FbHF84MdrPoE9sk}
```

I have API_SECRET, but how I decrypt payload in PHP?

I have tried below code by cloning library provided in below comment, but facing errors. Is anything wrong with the code?

```
require_once 'php-jwt/src/JWT.php';

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$key = "eyJhbG.....7PENIpC-E";

$payload = "eyJhbGc...FbHF84MdrPoE9sk";

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key);
$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));

print_r($decoded);
```

Comment: Is described [here](https://transak.stoplight.io/docs/transak-docs/docs/Tutorials/7.Webhook.md). Alternatively you can enter the JWT _eyJh...E9sk_ [here](https://jwt.io/) in the field _Encoded_. The key is only needed if you want to check the authenticity.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco for guiding on intial steps. can you guide me further? please check updated question

Comment: To decode the JWT, only the `JWT::decode()` call is needed. `$jwt` contains the JWT (_eyJh...E9sk_), `$key` the key (`HS256` as algo is OK). If this doesn't work, key and JWT possibly don't match. In the _firebase/jwt_ description you will find an HS256-[example](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example) that both encodes and decodes.